# Force Browserify to transform dependencies?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'm working on two Node packages at once, let's call them Library and Consumer. Library is responsible for rendering a bunch of stuff in the browser. All Consumer does is `import Library from 'library'` and call `Library(someConfigHere)` -- it's basically just a test to make sure Library is doing what I expect in the browser.

I've `npm link`ed Library into Consumer and am trying to run Browserify on Consumer, but I get this error: `ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`. Library does indeed contain an ES6 `export` statement, so I'm guessing that Browserify is only running against Consumer and not Library.

So my question is: **is there any way to force Browserify to transform dependencies as well**?

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "consumer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "budo index.js --port $PORT",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.12"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is Consumer's `index.js`:

```
import Library from 'library'  // <= this is what isn't getting babelified

console.log(Library);
```

This is Library's `index.js`:

```
export default (config) => {
    console.log('Testing testing')
}
```

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` file look like? A `ParseError` like that makes it sound like the TS Compiler isn't making it through the file.

Comment: @DaveV I'm not sure what the TS Compiler is. AFAIK the `ParseError` is a Babel thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browserify transforms can be configured to be global, which means they will be applied to files within `node_modules`, too.

The configuration is per-transform. With babelify, you'd configure it like this:

```
browserify().transform("babelify", {
  global: true
})
```

Or, if you are using the command line, like this:

```
browserify ... -t [ babelify --global ] ...
```

<s>Or, to configure it in the `package.json`, it should be something like this (note the added square brackets):</s>

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    ["babelify", { "global": true }]
  ]
}
```

Babelify also implements an `ignore` option, so it would be possible to configure it to transform only the files within `node_modules` that you want it to. There is more information [here](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed).

Another solution would be to include a similar `browserify`/`babelify` configuration in your `library` module's `package.json`. When processing dependencies, Browserify will check said dependency's `pacakge.json` files for transforms and will apply any that are configured.

Comment: This sounds like the solution, but would happen to know how to express that in the `browserify` section of `package.json`?

Comment: I'm getting an `Unexpected token 'g'` error when it hits `global: true`. I tried wrapping it in double quotes which silences that error, but still gives the original `ParserError`. It seems like babelify isn't honoring that setting.

Comment: Babelify should use the setting; I'm pretty sure I've used it in the past. It's possible/likely that browserify ignores the `global` setting when it's used in a `package.json` file. In fact, thinking about it, that is probably what's happening (I'd have to check the source to confirm). The other option would be to include a similar `browserify` setting in the `package.json` of the module you are consuming - then the `global` setting would not be required.